# Uninstall ubuntu full to windows

Tags: uninstall

I recently installed ubuntu one for windows and now would like to uninstall it. Problem is; there is no uninstall.exe to be found, I have fully converted the harddrive any idea how to revert back to windows 7?
I have a broken dvd driver aswell =/ so anything cd wise wouldnt help

Comment: So do you want to remove Ubuntu or Ubuntu One? The first is an app, the second is an operating system.

Comment: To be honest, Not sure, I click System Settings then Details the it says Ubuntu 12.04 LTS but on the side tehre is an ubuntu 1 that i havnt installed...

Comment: If you are in Windows 7, please tell us the names of any entries in Add/Remove Programs (in the Control Panel) that contain the word "Ubuntu." If you are not in Windows 7, please open a Terminal window (Ctrl+Alt+T) and run the command `mount; echo; df -h; echo; sudo parted -l`. You may be prompted for your password. As you enter it., you won't see anything happening (that's OK)--just type it in and press Enter. Then select all text in the Terminal, copy it to the clipboard, and **add it to your question by editing**. Select it in your question and format it with the `<$>` tool.

Comment: eliah kagan - www.imageshack.us/f/14/screenshotfrom201209132.png/ thats what happens when i put in mount

Answer (score 3):

Jason, if your question accurately describes the situation, then you simply installed the Ubuntu One Application for Windows into your windows 7 and you should still be booting into windows.  Whether or not you remove the application really should be fairly immaterial.  If you do not see it listed in the control panel app for uninstalling programs, you might need to remove it a different way or just ignore it.

If what you installed was actually Ubuntu (the OS), then how you answered questions during the install determined how it was loaded on the machine and whether it lives WITH your Windows or whether you wiped out the Windows system.

In other words, more details would be needed to give you a useful answer.

Comment: I believe i wiped the system

Answer (score 0):

If the hard drive has been formatted, then Windows 7 is gone. There is no way of getting your old Windows installation back. However, you can install a new one. Usually, that would be done with an installation CD. Since that is not an option, you should head to superuser.com and search for information about [installing Windows 7 from an USB drive.](https://superuser.com/questions/62193/install-windows-7-from-usb-flash-drive)

Comment: Ok i'm no good with the WINE,as you noted installing windows 7 from the USB drive ive uploaded it from another laptop to this one im currently on but its an .EXE, I tried running it it ddnt load, I tried using WINE as my friend said its something to do with the cross platform crap, So i tried that it still doesnt load? Any suggestions?

Comment: Use somebody else's Windows computer to make an installation USB drive.. but you really should try superuser.com, the site specializes in handling questions like this.